# Settings canvas object properties by id in Kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am relatively new to Kivy and need to do something seemingly simple, but which nonetheless eludes me: I need to set a line's position according to code.  The issue I am having is that my current code is structured around a future need to support gestures and has inherited some complexity due to being based on the showcase example app included with Kivy.

What I need to do is define the points of the line with id 'test' whenever the 'Front' screen is loaded.  That's it.  As the points will be variable, I know I'll need to do this outside of Front.kv

Here's my code (or see https://github.com/blyncsync/bs-user-app/ )

```
from time import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
from os.path import dirname, join
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.gesture import Gesture, GestureDatabase
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

#This database can compare gestures the user makes to its stored gestures 
#and tell us if the user input matches any of them.
gestures = GestureDatabase()

top_to_bottom_line = gestures.str_to_gesture('eNq1l0tu2zAQQPe6SLypwflzLpBuC+QARZoIidE2EWz3d/uSQ9uSU6deCNJG9njm8fMomlptvm5+/lk/9bv9j23ffTzch9StHgfo7m5e7r/3N92A5WO5Ube7u9ntt69f+135yt3q2yDd6iLkLtK6QSvKSv3wunnZ17Jcy/ydsk81qxug9aB24U8pAexu01rcJbEyuWLmLLU3v+uvVH9NAMAikDKJA2blbvfl/v+tcLQi3dOhAVHQ5J4MMBmXBp4O7MQuJJrIQEAl5evsGDjYiY0Z3RBIEdELdmRDFpMsQE7lY+Ffh+eA+xHOJqqixGrsBX/s+YfAI2XylByzlZlTuYrHmH2EpfAYeDriyetsUyJOIlbuM/FhFWUpfIjFk1jktiosoZVFV5fGiGciJhVCSVYc03V6mEVfhk4hlmAhenglWogeWkkWoodVOlkFb/sIEaA6+Tx4SCVfBM7hlE9OgTJOKELz6OGUT07LLlu7zJ5ZMJUR2Dx8SGVZCh9W2ZbCh1f2hfASZuVgtjJMGMyPm7HwvJ1Mwq3QYvyQK7IYP+yKnfggx3oULYy5/NArvhRfw6/CYvzwq6NfBMuEGaysTFZINpMfflUW44dfHf2i5JRPRzHNM//JNfzq6BfNTZAQPAMj+cz+W/i10S/RlIE0s/8Wfm30S5JcxiHgTHzotVEvWc5Igs4Aplwev2v8+rrwsO37l9Ph37Se/s261S0jr1N3y7mUd/vBcndfg1Rgk0tLhknL8JbRykwjmFMLYgRV1j69uGZAy4DIEGtl2IIpgpzeNloyaJoB1Mo4guD/dJKUW4a8m8H5Qiv6bjrBhXR7Lx2zXxh6nowBFVsPfRokOUdRyfA0zYA20Q7TYKILZdM5BT+UTacRcpt952nQvAXlLNgm3HUa1HyhVTvLaBY8nwXbwH068LLXRhBSOovavy1AgjcpZxNtkVLG3hb8c795et7X19JSfEt1PdcX1V+bx/1zRLkspzeq4sV6//qt396/PPSRJXGWq/HD0/l52L4+/nho5Cp8be6kVJ5zES7n4PLArf8CZ84KGA==',)
bottom_to_top_line = gestures.str_to_gesture('eNq1WMFuIzcMvc+PJJcaIimS0g+k1wL5gCJNjCTYbWI43rb79+VQmhmpme0UNcaHN84z+STx0ZKc29cvr398PzwfPy7fzsfh5/o8heH26QTD/c3bw+/Hm+GE9tYeNHzc33xczu9fjh/2Zxxuv554uF0Vufew4SSjlFr+6f317TKmpTEt/yDtlzFqOEGZwTiF75YCONz9FA6SOWXCCX06f40f03AXDgFZjJ8Qkgwfvz38+zDRh+HheRqBIoBiRTKF50kckqlOSITb4r500H3Ek4vnWZxJOVtuxUUbNCvghMi6qY1efIRdtNG1aRdtdxMXN6MlCoYJQa5SdztRd1J3PzHvo07uKC2OEjKS5IqRrxJ3S4n2EXdPifcRd0tpsRQx5JTThFequ6WU91GPbmmEndTd07h4CszEqBWjYqNu+5l1aEGKIW6ru6mRd1J3V+PiKmCMYqIFSdJV6u5qXFwNWSOpVLSebNQDRtvVHENm3hRnN5UXUwPHLCIThhwX9SCUzOiCduhtu8ruKtNe8m4rL7aGEFVJJoxtT9ppjYoVIcXtyrP7ytVXN4/JrCvIwbq1qPvIdopSqojBV7al785ynvUXVw3TvAO7PEOOacIktKkubq3ArC6JE8eK1iWteg7MaUKF7YuMuLNCs3rOUSk6stW6nTtgBkkV6T9sBuK+Ck/iQIEEeEKJ103dbZXZVjvw7ALHFRWuM1XcVJlNhZwTZ3aUsOyS/1Ne3VWdXUWUlEQqasRrGl7dVJ1NtY1bNUrFhPHKubutOtuKyXrZeqIg45ar42+Bx/Px+Dbf7FXGq73qcHtHiQ9huAMZH5eTpuFhJGNH5o5UJ1PoyGSDNy8aI6CNUDjk9qVjBLYRKaxEUImgEpHK0LEhbedbGZrbCJKSJi0p0KfJGKFtxDRaLQmOJIVSkpRbEuizVq71AY/A4Gm5liQ4SStTyNhFyEpEKYlmj4jUFy2OEaU+mkpELkNzSzIWspREtZBlbVk7stidSxVUnJS6nNyR4CSE0LFUWehY/rwwO3+7EK2Jdb1c2FTZ2LG5styyCmuDSBeCNVE7NlY2dSxXtlu1luayi0nHps+2AHQlSLUwgG250yRHrV05rMl1NudaLuCmPWIIKyUA6ULqYkE7VtdGTM2IdgupiblloVYUQ8eutKndcbuQWl5s6xFBVxaA1BQyQm0JjP9gV0bkNqR+KQGlY2sbo3bstKy2JSLS2uxqPeKPQyh0IdUBgk1t+w33ULb0l+Pr88vF/6limz/yaIbRf74+XV6cjbZhQiEv71+P54e3x6N/wH6+jnw9b349nd+fvj0WMbFeOrDNyY5G+wZJGm/idowc/gbsOJ0Z',)
left_to_right_line = gestures.str_to_gesture('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',)
right_to_left_line = gestures.str_to_gesture('eNqVWcty3DYQvPNHrItVGMwDwA8o11T5A1KKvSWrnEhb0jqJ/z4AGuRyrNWS3oNlNweN6Z7BEGvdPH57/OfH7cPh9fT95TD9Nn4ew3Tz5UjTpw9P938fPkzHWP9af/D0+unD6+nl+dvhtf5Tppu/jjrdXCT51MOmozWqVNcfnx+fTm1ZbsvKO8t+b1HTkZBBS+FHXUJxugu3IaQolqz+SZxDLLHl8197zu25aNESlPrzVESn1z/vr28jfRudHtoOH9sWHEoOFlgkR0tsVfPDoOcYgjDhWU1jm76Lp7SLnkvSSDrSz7SDPnf6so/eTHIKlou1PXiTPfYSRAJ7Iw+sYc4wsiQ6k7OKRs0W+wZm2+yxs/PCTsGKLvYWPpPHIiFxTKAv29S9qFHP1EkLaWlF02pByWdqK4UV9az0O0zpFY1p4Y6psEkcHUf1+cLtPcnb3L2csSzcXNtArCC32nAr7pCyWd2x21WrsknOvZpMO8hrc3DmkbZq2G5E7sVk3uEKtc4pNKdu22eUezn5XM5Yy5VJehtHjY1iJifi+YGQBNom7/XktKNXQp04OczDhWlH5r2gfC7ohfk1k8esOs5tK0iSTXbpFRXaw06SLJZldOXt3KWXVHj79Le5Q7WDltFV6bfPv/Sqiu7jl8Th7M6O7HtZZc/gbQ+zRv6V0Si9sLIevKZiPA6N6tI2H1tTOnPS9lnVXlmlffR19tKqttvsvbLKK/ZSihjhwIvllfNkqRSdnaGyPcW0F1ZXr1SqicWcceLrUFw5H6k00nm273ilaq+sripLNbvqMSZKlCAret83Oy4E2iurZR99yizn+8b2tLFeWFsVNlZHivCwt76gz+y1YTlJWT7bZ8p6ZY330XPtqmVWsm5bb72ytqpsPTU5zb1dz++K3fVN3J5m1utqaRd5icS/9IKyXlYre9jFG7PjLpN6WdO+sop3Zoc1qZc18a6eFOeNlB30vaxp34FVP8z6Zax9J/j8cjg8LTf8ZO2Kn9J0c6eFb8N0x9Hqj9Mx5em+gdGBBSCtwRwABoDa3hDnj7UIchGCZbGDOTuQASYHCkAFyAAVoDjQALIDE0ByIOTl4EDIS2UNFshLyYFQlFxKBYqS271AUXK7FyhKbvcCRZYdCEXmd4ciMwdCkfmUoMhcShQgyaJHocnIoxBlrna12zqqyaOQpfJuJ1CASKUrIZAsed1kFKBZdEbL+iM9BA7IEJvHQlgg5FCCBTw2KQOFBQxjOQwUFjDsYrqQM8GPCLoe2VD4Ec2jsCCyR6E6Ro9CdSSPQmgMM/rWC4Jqyu+HRFhAdiUEfpBeCYE5JFdCYA7FKyFwKpSfn70XDw/DNXkwNKQrIXA3XMsdVgdfgNjdra98h3IAmjxKQNWjEeiVnuJum4wBOTcjC1B2jcvdD5kn12hyNqBXzgx3C8T8YeMM1DwK1XWYvCnSHCKwYJ4sl463wA8tV0JgzjxdLobAHFU3gATmKHsU5qgfYQJz2pjx7KsQmCPmF8Ic+WkTmCN+eir8qGPmrWVzCPzg5BfCApYrC2EB+ymusCAWj8KCMYniaEKFBVE9CtVRPArVjfCNXXMILBgjbEYtOHQkZHQxNl6MhdAxBJfYITR4FEKpvJ+m2fsh4cIRMfgxRunlEJhD6UoIzCHduWuCbUR742HomGVxTIvUDa3XW492Q3lMlrdGtJDuLo+BcjlEEYIC0Jg5qbvLJh7tHvI40d2nhmag7NHuFI/3/4zilsnjLC4oARWPQrV4XtwtWaJHIXSc2wWFNgkehTYuHoU2/ilfaGP1KLSxzwFXTI6eAXdMjt5JXDJ5HJEFhbbRgBfLhTsnj3f53Aq4dM7o5YVQPV7fy0KopuBRqA7Zo1AdXBdG3EI5qEeh2vdxxC2UA3uUL8bKxdgqFF+Bvh4eH76e2u9K2mmqyv1h6r86+ffxy+lrD0nTXexfXCp6ev7r8HL/9Ln/oqXeNtt/ZDZ8fF374/jy/OX7Z1CXuu42h2pQyCnUeayS2tff2/8BU0ImLg=='  )

gestures.add_gesture(top_to_bottom_line)
gestures.add_gesture(bottom_to_top_line)
gestures.add_gesture(left_to_right_line)
gestures.add_gesture(right_to_left_line)

def simplegesture(name, point_list):
    """
    A simple helper function
    """
    g = Gesture()
    g.add_stroke(point_list)
    g.normalize()
    g.name = name
    return g

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    fullscreen = BooleanProperty(False)

    def add_widget(self, *args):
        if 'content' in self.ids:
            return self.ids.content.add_widget(*args)
        return super(HomeScreen, self).add_widget(*args)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # start collecting points in touch.ud
        # create a line to display the points
        userdata = touch.ud
        with self.canvas:
            #Color(1, 1, 0)
            #d = 30.
            #Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            userdata['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

        event_handled = False
        for child in self.children:
            if not event_handled:
                if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
                    event_handled = True

        if not event_handled:
            print touch.x, touch.y

        #return True

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # store points of the touch movement
        try:
            touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
            return True
        except (KeyError) as e:
            pass

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # touch is over, check if it matches some known gesture.
        g = simplegesture('', list(zip(touch.ud['line'].points[::2],
                                       touch.ud['line'].points[1::2])))

        # use database to find the more alike gesture, if any
        g2 = gestures.find(g, minscore=0.70)

        print(g2)
        if g2:
            if g2[1] == left_to_right_line:
                print("left_to_right_line")
            if g2[1] == right_to_left_line:
                print("right_to_left_line")
            if g2[1] == top_to_bottom_line:
                print("top_to_bottom_line")
            if g2[1] == bottom_to_top_line:
                print("bottom_to_top_line")

class HomeApp(App):
    index = NumericProperty(-1)
    current_title = StringProperty()
    time = NumericProperty(0)
    show_sourcecode = BooleanProperty(False)
    sourcecode = StringProperty()
    screen_names = ListProperty([])
    hierarchy = ListProperty([])

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'BlyncSync'
        self.screens = {}
        self.available_screens = [
            'Login', 'Register', 'Forgot Password', 'Front']
        self.screen_names = self.available_screens
        curdir = dirname(__file__)
        self.available_screens = [join(curdir, 'data', 'screens',
            '{}.kv'.format(fn)) for fn in self.available_screens]
        self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.available_screens)
        screen = self.load_screen(self.index)
        sm = self.root.ids.sm
        sm.switch_to(screen, direction='left')
        self.current_title = screen.name

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass

    def go_screen(self, idx):
        self.index = idx
        self.root.ids.sm.switch_to(self.load_screen(idx), direction='left')

    def load_screen(self, index):
        if index in self.screens:
            return self.screens[index]
        screen = Builder.load_file(self.available_screens[index].lower())
        self.screens[index] = screen
        return screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HomeApp().run()
```

Front.kv

```
HomeScreen:
    name: 'Front'

    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, .1, .1, .9
            SmoothLine:
                id: test
                points: (100, 100, 200, 200)
```

To be specific, I'd like to define test.points as such:

```
scale = 50 # 0 < scale < 100; arbitrary/defined programmatically
angle = scale/100*180 # convert a scale from 0-100 to an angle from 0-180
length = 100 # arbitrary
center_x = 100
center_y = 100
test.points = (center_x, center_y, center_x + length*cos(angle), center_y + length*sin(angle))
```

I've tried adding the following snippet to load_screen, to no avail:

```
    if str(self.screens[index].name) == 'Front':
        self.ids.test.points = (100, 100, -300, 300)
```

Thank you for reading and I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's nice to see more code than less code if the issue is interesting, but... why do you post empty functions such as `on_pause`? If it's empty, it only makes your code longer.

Next thing, [`ids`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L1130) are probably widget-only, but even if not, this code will show you that there's no such thing for [Instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            id: test
            size:self.size
            pos:self.pos
    Button:
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        print '\n'*2, self.ids, '\n'*2
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kw)
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Even if it'd have a possibility to use `id`, it'd still be already drawn and you couldn't do anything with it except [clearing canvas](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Canvas.clear)(which would clear widgets too). Imagine this as MsPaint, where your eraser is basically `Ctrl+A` & `delete`.

What you can do is using another widget with its canvas(don't know if you want to use that FloatLayout for anything else except drawing) e.g. StencilView("cropped" canvas) or simple Widget would do... or even that FloatLayout.

Then set an `id` for that *widget* and code with this:

```
with <your id>.canvas:  # or canvas.before / canvas.after
    # instructions here e.g.:
    SmoothLine(points=<variable>)
```

Comment: I am sorry for spamming you / wasting your time, but I do thank you for your response

Let me chew through this and see if I can't make something of it
Take tips?

Comment: Hm... I didn't intend to sound rude or something O.o Anyway(tldr): Cleaner code usually = better code(at least for reading); Canvas is a list of instructions so to know how it works you need to read the `graphics` part of the docs; You can set ids only to widget, but you are able to access the canvas through widget (last example)

Comment: I have not figured this out yet...  I am just going to scrap what I have and restart.

I just need to animate a line's points, basically.  But damn does Kivy seem cumbersome to me for some reason.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'HomeScreen' object has no attribute 'viewid' :/ time to read...

Comment: That's only because you call something, that's not in `HomeScreen` object available(set/written/...). For this kind of errors is nice to do a `print <variable that causes the error>` or a simple look is good if you have something like `my_widget.something_here.something_there.blah.<variable>`. If you set an id for that `FloatLayout`, you'd need to do `HomeScreen.ids.<that id>` (or `self.`)